# How can I fix Lossy Conversion in java?

Tags: java

So this is my code:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class LabScratch
    { 
     public static void main(String args[]) { 
     int i, sum = 0, diff = 0, ctr = 0; 
     double j = 0.0, ave = 0.0; 
     
     double [] A = new double [10];
     int [] B = new int [10];
     System.out.println("Enter 10 integers: ");
     Scanner input1 = new Scanner (System.in);
     Scanner input2 = new Scanner (System.in);       
     
     for (i = 0; i < A.length; i++) { // getting average
         A [i] = input1.nextDouble(); 
         sum += A[i];
         ctr++; }
         
         A [j] = ave;
         System.out.println("\n" + A [j]);
         
 }
 }
```

and when I try to run it, it says
"error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int
A [j] = ave;
^
error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int
System.out.println("\n" + A [j]);'

Comment: The lossy conversion it's because when you're trying to access an element from an array you expect an integer (element 0, 1, 2, 3...) not a double number (element 1.00236? that doesn't exists!).

Answer (score 0):

The variable I and j both need to be of the same data type.
You are accessing the array using the I which is of int data type and then later trying to assign a value at a specific index using the j variable which is of a different data type.

Answer (score 0):

seems you need to simply declare j as int rather than double:

```
 int i, sum = 0, diff = 0, ctr = 0, j = 0; 
 double ave = 0.0;
```